# make a tag not effected by a body class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have set my body width to 600px so when moused outside of the body, the body turns to an opacity of 0.25.  I have that setting being applied directly to the body tag by jquery adding a class to it and when the body is moused over, the class (opac) is removed.  when moused out of, i want buttons that have a fixed position outside of the body that previously had the opac class applied to it, not be affected by it any more.  the buttons will be brought up to an opacity of 1 (which if i am not mistaken, is the normal setting for items so they are fully in view).  currently, when the body is moused over, the buttons do have a opacity of 0.25 but when the body is moused out of, the buttons stay the same opacity and when the buttons are moused over, it brings both the body and buttons to an opacity of 1.

Comment: You can't place an element inside an element that has opacity set lower, and expect the child to have higher opacity, it's just not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements inside the body will inherit the 0.25 opacity of their parent (`<body>`in this case, ). Your best bet is instead to use a structure like the following:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

And now you can apply the opacity on :hover to `.container` and position the buttons in `.buttons` accordingly.

Comment: thanks but we are not allowed to use <div>, is there any other way to get around this?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly what your internal requirements may be, but you could instead use `<section class="container">` and `<aside class="buttons">`. Mind you, I don't know what the motivation is behind your limitations so my apologies if this isn't helpful.

Comment: Good, I'm glad that was useful. Was this able to solve your problem? If so, I'd be grateful if you'd mark my answer as accepted. If not, let me know what you're still running up against and hopefully I'll be able to help further.

Comment: This did solve my problem, I am new to HTML and was unaware of what the <section> tag did for me, implementing this I was able to achieve what I wanted. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use opacity for this.

If you set opacity to mother element, all child elements will retake this setup.

Use **RGBa** for colors and prefer **:hover** selector instead of jquery.